# How to cache every call made for an offline web experience

Tags: caching, squid, offline-browsing

I'm going up to the mountains with no internet connection to present something. I'd like to be able to use interactive examples since I'll be presenting on a certain website.

So is there a way I can set up a proxy caching server or something to cache every call made in order to have a fully cached website experience with no internet connection?

I've looked at http://squidman.net/ but I'm not sure how it works or how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try something like this. It might be a lot more work than the steps below, but this could be a good starting point.

- Create a local proxy server along with memcache or redis
- Update the browser proxy settings to use your proxy server details
- Make the local server look for the url in the redis server.

  - If found, return the data in the redis server
  - Else, do a web request and store the data in the redis server

You'll have to do this manually for the pages that you want while you have the internet connection. Once you've got all the data you need, you can work without the internet connection too.

Comment: Can you point me to somewhere to help me set up a proxy server with memcache or redis?

Comment: I haven't come across such a thing. I've worked with a proxy server and with redis and the solution above just uses them both together :)

Answer (score 2):

If the pages are essentially static then you could use something like HTTrack http://www.httrack.com/ to make an offline copy

If there's anything requiring server side interaction or dynamic generation of pages you're most likely going to need to run your own local instance of the server.